# Can't connect as different user while accessing network share with in domain network in Mac

Tags: mac, network, sharing, domain

Can't connect as different user while accessing network share with in domain network in Mac.
Through Go > Connect to server > connect as

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I am logged in with userA. I can see all of the shares. I want to access a specific share that userA does not have access to that userB does. I disconnect from server, but 'connect as' does not do anything when I click it

I found a workaround:

1. Go to Finder
2. Click Go, then Connect to Server
3. Create a path of smb://userB@myserver

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7988659?answerId=31890794022#31890794022